# create file attribute to customer image error occur in magento 2.3.6

Tags: magento2.3, file-upload

create custom file attribute for customer, it is not compulsory or required to field but if file is not uploaded then throw error `Uncaught TypeError: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, bool given in C:\xampp73\htdocs\magento236\vendor\magento\module-customer\Model\Customer\Attribute\Validator\File.php`.

How to solve it in Magento 2.3.6?

Comment: Please provide more details like which php version you are using, and also have you used any third party/custom extension which is related to customer attribute?

Answer (score 0):

incase anyone is still in need of a solution. The problem was that there were some customer custom attributes that had not values or were null. Since I did not need those attributes. I removed the attributes from the DB. I removed the attributes manually from the tables: customer_form_attribute, eav_attribute, and customer_eav_attribute.

If you decide to remove manually, make sure you have a backup of your DB incase the wrong attribute is deleted.

-Ray